# jQuery select dropdown value based on value of other dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get my head around jQuery, but I have trouble figuring out plain arrays vs jQuery arrays, and DOM elements vs jQuery elements.

So here's an example I try to do. The example is simple really, but I need some hand-holding :-p so I'll be verbose in my requirements hoping that the answers will be, in turn, descriptive.

I have two `<select>` drop-downs, with IDs `#version` and `#target`.

When I click a button, I want to select in `#target` the option *following* with the same name as the *last-but-one* value in `#version`. (the item WILL exist)

Example: `#version` has options: a,b,c,x. `#target` has options a,b,c,d,h,m.

I click the button. What should happen is:

- read the last-but-one option in `#version`: "c"
- find the option with the same name in `#target`: the 3rd (i.e. index is 2)
- set the selected value in `#target` to the one after "c", i.e. "d" (the 4th, index 3)

[Here's a fiddle with the example.](http://jsfiddle.net/GpBDY/1/)

For the 1st step, I think I figured it out:

```
var latestVersion = $("#version option").get(-2).text;
```

//side-note: why does `.text` work but not `.val()` ? oh, `.get()` returns a DOM element
// so How do I get back to a jQuery element?
// `$($("#version option").get(-2)).val()` works but looks ugly

For step 2, I tried this:

```
var target = $("#target option:contains(latestVersion)");
```

but it doesn't work. And there's GOT to be a better way than manually iterating all the values searching for the right one.

Step 3: ??.

Comment: you want [This](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/GpBDY/6/) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using 1st step as you figured try the following:

```
$('#button').click(function(){     
var latestVersion = $("#version option").get(-2).text;
//index of LAST-BUT-ONE
var target=$("#target option[value="+latestVersion+"]").index();
//Setting next index value
$("#target").prop("selectedIndex",target + 1);    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GpBDY/16/

Comment: This looks like the most straight-forward answer so far + it hits all my requirements. SOLD!

Answer (score 1):

.val() does not work on an option element, but it does work on a select element:

```
var v = $( "#version" ).val();
```

gives you the element selected in the dropdown #version.

The following line will not do what you want:

```
var target = $("#target option:contains(latestVersion)");
```

That is because latestVersion is treated as the value "latestValue" and not as the name of a variable. To use the value of the variable latestValue, put latestValue outside the string like:

```
... contains(" + latestVersion + ")...
```

You might be interested in the jQuery method [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) in combination with your code in step 2 to get the value of the next option element. Be aware that if there is no next element, the value will be "undefined".

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `nth-child` to select value of `version` and using that set the value of `target` this way:

```
$('#button').click(function(){     
    var latestVersion = $("#version option:nth-child(3)").text();
    $("#target").val($('#target option[value="'+latestVersion+'"]').next().text());    
});
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GpBDY/5/)

Comment: I don't always want the 3rd element from the first select - the values are populated dynamically.  I want the (N-1)th element. However, +1 for the selector for the 2nd select.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure i understand you are looking for, but i think that you want something like this:

```
$('#button').click(function(){ 
    var arrVersion = $("#version option");

    var latestVersion = $(arrVersion[arrVersion.length  - 2]).val();

    $("#target").val(latestVersion);
   var actualSelected = parseInt($("#target").prop("selectedIndex"));
    $("#target").prop("selectedIndex", actualSelected + 1);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GpBDY/9/